# Footer Including Non Footer Items In Footer

Tags: css, html

Sorry if the title doesn't explain it. I have footer and it includes whatever is above the footer. If I have text above the footer (as a sibling of the footer tag) the footer includes the text as part of the footer. Here is my code:

```
<section id="description">
    <div id="description1">
        <div class="container">
            <h3><em>text</em></h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="description2">
        <div class="container">
            <h3><em>text</em></h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <p id="copywrite">AllKind Corporation, Copyright &copy; 2018</p>
        <a href="credits.html" id="credits">Credits</a>
        <p id=disclaimer>By using this site, you agree to our <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="toc.html">Terms of Conditions</a>.</p>
        <p id="license">
            <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/">
                <img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-nd/4.0/88x31.png" />
            </a>
            <br />This website is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License</a>.
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

For some reason my footer is including the description (a child of `<section id="description">`) in the footer. I have narrowed the issue down to having to do with the `float: right;` tag in the CSS for `description2`.

Here is my CSS for the description and footer.

```
/* Description */
#description1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#description2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

/* Footer */
footer {}

#copywrite {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#credits {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
}

#disclaimer {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -28px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#license img {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -27px;
}

#license {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to say. What you really want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have the description and footer separate.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "text"? Like a <p> tag? It would help if you tell us in your question exactly what behavior you want to see, and give us an example of exactly what behavior you want (what kinds of siblings should be included in the footer, precisely?) Great question otherwise.

Comment: One tiny thing - it looks like the first line of code isn't indented quite properly, and that makes it a bit less readable.

Comment: Yep, I struggle with the formatting on S.O. a lot! It's finicky. If you delete two spaces right before the <section> tag that would fix it though :)

Comment: I would like to separate the description (as in the children of `<section id="description">`) and the footer (as in the children of `<footer>`). The thing that tells me they are combined is that if I put padding at the top of the footer, it will actually display as padding at the top of the description even though they are siblings. And yeah, the indentation is messed up with stack overflow for some reason. In the actual code it's proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the float first. The issue you are facing is due to the floating elements

```css
 #description1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 18px;
   float: left;
   padding-left: 100px;
   padding-top: 30px;
 }

 #description2 {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 18px;
   float: right;
   padding-right: 100px;
   padding-top: 30px;
 }
/*This is to clear the float*/
 .clearfix {
   clear: both
 }

 /* Footer */

 footer {}

 #copywrite {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 13px;
 }

 #credits {
   font-size: 18px;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-align: left;
 }

 #disclaimer {
   font-size: 15px;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: -28px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
 }

 #license img {
   float: right;
   margin-top: -27px;
 }

 #license {
   font-size: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-bottom: -2px;
 }
```

```html
<section id="description">
  <div id="description1">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><em>text</em></h3>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="description2">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><em>text</em></h3>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="clearfix"></div><!--Clearing the float -->

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="copywrite">AllKind Corporation, Copyright &copy; 2018</p>
    <a href="credits.html" id="credits">Credits</a>
    <p id=disclaimer>By using this site, you agree to our <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="toc.html">Terms of Conditions</a>.</p>
    <p id="license">
      <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/">
                <img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-nd/4.0/88x31.png"/>
                </a>
      <br />This website is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License</a>.
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Note the clearfix element and the class in CSS

Here is the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/4533/

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, I forgot to test it. It works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick way to separate the section from the footer you can add the following to the CSS ...

```
#description {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Maybe explain a bit more what you want to achieve.

UPDATE: The best way is the clearing the float though as mentioned in another answer.. You can apply the  clear: both directly to the footer without adding another DIV

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear, I don't really know how to explain it other than the footer and description are combined when they aren't supposed to be. It's as if the description is a child of the footer even though they are both siblings in the actual code. I have tried to clear the float, but that doesn't work in separating them.

Comment: You just said what was missing  " the footer and description are combined when they aren't supposed to be. " hehehe ..  just add the clear:both to the footer CSS you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this:-

```css
#description1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
 width:50%;
}

#description2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
 width:50%;
}

/* Footer */
footer {}

#copywrite {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#credits {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
}

#disclaimer {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -28px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#license img {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -27px;
}

#license {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="description">
    <div id="description1">
        <div class="">
            <h3><em>text</em></h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="description2">
        <div class="">
            <h3><em>text</em></h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <p id="copywrite">AllKind Corporation, Copyright &copy; 2018</p>
        <a href="credits.html" id="credits">Credits</a>
        <p id=disclaimer>By using this site, you agree to our <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="toc.html">Terms of Conditions</a>.</p>
        <p id="license">
            <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/">
                <img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-nd/4.0/88x31.png" />
            </a>
            <br />This website is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License</a>.
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

If you want like this then i will explain it.